# Ubuntu 32 Bit boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, 32-bit

I'm having trouble getting to boot to 32 bit Ubuntu from a 64 bit machine. Everything I'm reading says there shouldn't be an issue.

I've been able to boot from the 64 bit version when installed on a USB but not when I use the 32 bit version. When I go into the BIOS the computer sees the USB but fails to boot from it. When I then start windows I get the option to boot to Windows 10 or Ubuntu, but trying Ubunutu fails and it goes to Windows.

Comment: Just a guess, Ubuntu 32bit has no UEFI support, while 64bit does.